# How to rotate n individual’s in a Facebook group, so everybody meets everybody.

Tags: combinatorics

I’m part of an eating support group, we follow Bright Line Eating. We are part of a competition to stay Bright. In order to stay Bright we need to support each other. We pair up each week. I have
22 people for 12 weeks. But we’ve already been going for 12 weeks. So far I have just rotated the odd column but then I realized the evens would never meet and the odds would never meet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please clarify the problem; it's a little difficult to understand exactly what the issue issue is. Then add what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Use this method to get everyone a new pair for $21$ weeks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm